# Python: Recreating rose plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

For an assignment, I am trying to recreate the rose plot
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nmax=101 # choose a high number to "smooth out" lines in plots
x_angle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,nmax) # create an array x for bottom right 
y_br = abs(np.cos(3*x_angle)) # y for the bottom right subplot

# bottom right subplot controls
plt.plot(x_angle, y_br, 'tab:blue')
```

[image]

Is there a way to get it to look any closer to the original plot (e.g. make the petals narrower, set tick marks to 0.0, 0.5, 1.0)?

Comment: Have you tried changing `nmax`?

Comment: Just make your figure smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use polar projection for this type of plot:

- for the ticks, it is set by `rticks`
- for the petals, it is controlled by the `nmax` feature

Here is a code that gives a better drawing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nmax=int(1e5) # choose a high number to "smooth out" lines in plots
x_angle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,nmax) # create an array x for bottom right 
y_br = abs(np.cos(3*x_angle)) # y for the bottom right subplot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.plot(x_angle, y_br, lw= 3)
ax.set_rticks([0, 0.5, 1])  # Less radial ticks
```